# IntPredicate Lambda Java8

Tags: lambda, filter, java-8, predicate

The functionality of the following method is to try to traverse a list from 3 to 999 by adding the multiples of two numbers, where `multiplosDe.get(0)` could be 4 and `multiplosDe.get(1)` could be 7.

This function works if I only send a list with two Integer objects. What I want is to be able to send a list of n objects and do not have to have the need to add  `|| multiplosDe.get(2)` to predicate.

```
public long sumaDeMultiplos(List<Integer> multiplosDe) {
    int suma = 0;
    IntPredicate predicate  = s -> (s%multiplosDe.get(0)==0 || s%multiplosDe.get(1)==0);

        suma = IntStream.range(3, 1000).filter(predicate).sum();

    return suma;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IntPredicate predicate  = s -> multiplosDe.stream().anyMatch(i -> s % i == 0);
```